# SVN Checkout keeps missing files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using windows 7 64 bit.I tired doing checkout with tortoise 1.8.7 and 1.7.0 but every time after a certain moment I get errors like connection rejected,error e175002 and sometimes Svn crashes.
I am doing cleanup and update but after several attempts its get updated to the current revision but misses out on some files in the process. I have tired with GUI,CommandLine.
http,https.

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Which version the your server is running on? Are you using externals?

Comment: I am doing the checkout from a remote location, cloudforge.com.

Comment: Are you trying to check out an entire repository, or just one folder (e.g. trunk)? If the former, maybe try checking out only one folder to reduce the size of your checkout.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.My windows had issues,I re installed and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue once. I've solved it by using `svn://` protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.My windows had issues,I re installed and it worked fine